# Working on a SMA type cross of a candle but the single is showing over and over

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am running into an issue while creating a cross but the cross is on a candle Close. I got that part pretty much ok'ish, but the label continues to be over each and every candle that is either above or below where the line has crossed.

WVMA1 = ta.vwma(close, 30)

openlong = ta.cross(open, WVMA1) and open > WVMA1 and close >= WVMA1
closelong = open < WVMA1 and close < WVMA1

plotshape(series=openlong, title="30 Long", style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, text="30 Long", textcolor=color.black, size=size.normal)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hN5EW.png)plotshape(series=closelong, title="30 Short", style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, text="30 Short", textcolor=color.white, size=size.normal)

Really just need the marker to show up once, once triggered but searching has so far failed me.  So hoping one of y'all awesome folks can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Actually doing some more googling actually figured something out that fixes this so far..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use crossover instead of cross to get signal only when crossover occurs Also you can track current pos in a variable and based on that you can close open long position

```
//@version=5
indicator("Matrix test", overlay = true)

WVMA1 = ta.vwma(close, 30)
var currentpos=0
openlong = ta.crossover(open, WVMA1) and open > WVMA1 and close >= WVMA1 
if openlong
    currentpos:=1
closelong = open < WVMA1 and close < WVMA1 and currentpos==1
if closelong
    currentpos:=0

plotshape(series=openlong, title="30 Long", style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, text="30 Long", textcolor=color.black, size=size.normal)

plotshape(series=closelong, title="30 Short", style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, text="30 Short", textcolor=color.white, size=size.normal)
```

[image]